# design pattern - solving dependencies

Tags: c++, qt

Lets say in C++/Qt I have class A, class B and HTTP class which is a singleton and handles GET requests.

Object of class A sends GET request (thanks to instance of HTTP class) and it waits for reply. When it appears, its parsed, appropriate models are populated etc.

Object of class B should do the same but additionally it needs some data parsed inside object of class A.

I know I can do that by Qt signals/slots mechanism but I'd like to use kind of design pattern cuz there are much more classes that needs to support such operation. In my case for example one object needs to wait for data received by 3 other objects. Is there any way to solve that kindly?

Comment: Perhaps you could use some form of event queue that will send on any events to registered modules/classes? Observer or command pattern could also be potentially used.

Comment: Qt's signals and slots mechanism **is** the observer pattern

Answer (score 0):

Observer pattern is what you are looking for
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern